# How to find the closest line to two segments?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, computational-geometry

I have two segments in 2D space, defined by their endpoint x and y coordinates.
How can I find a best-fit line using vector algebra (formally, that minimizes the integral of square-distance from it to every bit of the segments)? Is such a line unique?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How do you define a "best fit line"... that is the question.

Maybe a solution is to find $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that if the line $(L)$ is defined by $y=ax+b$ then $\sum_{i=1}^4 d^2(L,P_i)$ is minimum where $P_1, \dots, P_4$ are the end points of the two segments. That is what you suggest by minimizing the integral of square-distance.

Comment: Would that be equivalent to changing the sum to an integral, and Pi to be any points, instead of endpoints of the segments? Is it possible to find this line using just vector algebra such as vector summation, dot and cross products (no calculus for calculations or explicit usage of trigonometry, apart from proof that it's a correct solution)?